# Different naming for different company types in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Users registering on our site will have different company types (doctors, attorneys, etc) and will thus have different jargon throughout the app.  For example, a doctor will see "Practice Information" and an attorney would see "Firm Information".

Is this a job for locales in Rails 3, or is there a better method or even gem?

Comment: IMO, locales is good for this. Create files like `doctor.en.yml`, `attorney.en.yml`. Or maybe broader names like `medical.en.yml`/`law.en.yml`.. whatever feels best.

Comment: @Zabba: Thanks!  But where do I put the logic to determine which locale to use?

Answer (score 1):

Locales would work well in this case.  You can set the local during your controller processing before the view starts to be processed.  Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html for a lot of great details on how to manage and load your yml files, and how to set your default and change your locale per request.  Basically you just need to do something like:

```
before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
   I18n.locale = @user.company_type_locale_code
end
```